# jsplumb not connecting between nested divs

Tags: jquery, jsplumb

I am having some issues trying to get jsplumb to draw a connector between 2 divs that are nested in column divs.

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chrisp_68/5YwVu/6/) that shows the issue, can anyone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

since the two elements you are connecting have different parents, you need to use the 'Container' concept:

http://jsfiddle.net/sporritt/5YwVu/9/

http://jsplumb.org/doc/content.html#containerDefault

Answer (score 2):

Try taking away the absolute positioning.

See http://jsfiddle.net/chrisp_68/5YwVu/8/

Comment: after hours of searching this was the answer for me. For those using ReactJS, order is really important - so set the `position:absolute` of the parent div AFTER you've set `draggable()` and `makeSource`/`makeTarget`

Answer (score 1):

Looks like jsfiddle examples above doesn't work, so i wrote small working example for jsPlumb 1.7.5

```
jsPlumb.ready(function() {
  var container = document.body;
  jsPlumb.setContainer(container);

  ...

  jsPlumb.connect({
    source: container.querySelector("#div1"),
    target: container.querySelector("#div2")
  });
})
```

full example http://plnkr.co/edit/8uwriJCdJ77N4w9xJfzU?p=preview